# Change fragment using mvvm pattern

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out the details of the mvvm pattern on android using android binding.

so using android binding and mvvm, which class should be responsible for the code for starting new activity or changing fragments in an activity?

In some examples i have seen, the viewmodel has a reference to the current context of the activity. but from my understanding this is actually mixing viewmodel and view, which is what we are trying to separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a navigation concern, you should create a navigation service interface and inject it into your ViewModels and in the concrete implementation of the navigation service you inject the current context or the application context.

Since activities and fragments are usually navigated to via intents which use the full qualified class name (usually using `MyClass.class`) this would cause a tight coupling to `MyClass` in this case, so you have to  use strings instead (that you store in a `final static` field for example).

So instead of `MyClass.class` you'd use `NavigationConstants.MyClass` where `NavigationCostants.MyClass` would be `public static final string MyClass = MyClass.class.getName()`